# Class 'App\Models\Dosen' not found laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**DosenController.php**

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
use App\Models\Dosen
```

**Dosen.php**

```php
<?php
    
namespace App;
namespace App\models;
```

when I changing use `App\Models\Dosen;` to `App\Dosen;`, but Class `'App\Dosen'` is not found

Comment: you have two namespace .remove namespace App; first one in model

Comment: `"namespace App\models;" !== "namespace App\Models;"`

Answer (score 1):

First you have two namespace in your model

```
namespace App;
namespace App\models;
```

and second in your controller you have used Capital `M` .But in model you have small letter m.
so you should correct `Dosen.php`.First remove both namespace in `Dosen.php` and add it like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
```

To Avoid namespace issue in you model.You can create model using php artisan command

```
php artisan make:model Dosen
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: I've changed it, but the error Use of undefined constant dosen - assumed 'dosen' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: can you show both model controller full code

Comment: Be aware that this is case sensitive. If it is actually spelled "dosen" then write "Dosen" instead and change every call regarding the Dosen model in your code to upper-case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the first namespace

```
 <?php
  namespace App;
```

then change the namespace to  `namespace App\Models;`.

after these changes you can use your model inside your controller

Comment: I've changed it, but the error Use of undefined constant dosen - assumed 'dosen' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP

Comment: which php version do you use

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel7 , Models was in App Folder , so :

DosenController.php

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
use App\Dosen; // edit this line
```

Dosen.php

```
<?php
    
namespace App;
// namespace App\models; // remove this line
```